# Why don't these concatenate statements work?

Tags: excel-formula

Excel 2019

I'm trying to concatenate some text values and I'm having trouble. All of the shown cells are formatted as text. The first row works fine but none of the other statements resolve. I'm sure it's me but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be most appreciated and I apologize for being thick. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Change the format to "General".

Comment: Done. No change.

Comment: make sure you do not have a space or other unprintable character or `'` in front of the formula.  make sure the whole column C is formatted "General" then save and close and reopen.  If none of those work, I am out of guesses.

Comment: No spaces or extra characters in the front. Formulas in the screenshot are "as is". I really do appreciate you taking the time to help me out sir. Thank you!